# C# in Depth: Problem set?

Tags: c#, c#-3.0

Right now I am reading "C# in Depth". One of the thing missing is the set of problems that I can go through once I finish a chapter. That would have helped me understand the concepts that I just learned.

Any place where I can find good problem sets for C#3.0 stuff?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try [LINQ 101 samples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336746.aspx), they are pretty much cover most of C# 3.0 & Linq stuff, you can see the problem and try to rewrite the code